# Click on Expandable ListView parent component not opening child list

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I make a Expandable list but when i click on parent but it not open child component and its close its. What is wrong happening i don't know.  If any one say i also provide snapshot. I tried many thing but nothing is happened. I thing all these happen bcoz adding scroll view before adding scroll view these work perfectly. But not Its not working check my xml file if any error found please inform me.

My MainActivity.java:-

```
  ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild =  new HashMap<String, List<String>>();;
List<String> innerhref = new ArrayList<>();
 //   private List<String> firstLevelSubMenus = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
   // prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.discount_and_offers);
    view = findViewById(R.id.discount_and_offers_view);

    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.grad_offer_details);

    linearLayout01 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_inner_image01);


    linearLayoutDiscount01 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_inner_discount_image01);

    linearLayoutmens =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.line3);

    linearLayoutMens01 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_inner_mens_image01);
    linearLayoutMens02 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_inner_mens_name01);
    linearLayoutMens03 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_inner_mens_price01);


    mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

   new Menus().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/menu&key=test123$");

    new ImageSlider().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/slider&key=test123$");

    new SpecialProduct().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/specialproduct&key=test123$");

    new DiscountProduct().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/discountproduct&key=test123$");

    new FrontCategories().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/getfrontcategories&key=test123$");

}
public class Menus extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(status==200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    listDataHeader.add(jsonObject1.getString("name"));

                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("children");

                    for(int j=0;j<jsonArray1.length();j++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                        List<String> innerChild = new ArrayList<>();
                        innerChild.add(jsonObject2.getString("name"));
                        innerhref.add(jsonObject2.getString("href"));

                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i),innerChild);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException |JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

My XMl:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

        </ExpandableListView>

        <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </FrameLayout>

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <!--        <View
                android:id="@+id/grad_offer_details_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>  -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grad_offer_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Grab Before Time Runs Out"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/yellow_draw_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#FF00FF00"/>


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer_image01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_image01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/line1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Hello"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text__"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Hello"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/discount_and_offers_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#d3d3d3"/>
            <!-- android:background="@android:color/gray" -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discount_and_offers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Discount And Offers"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/green_draw_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#FF00FF00"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer_discount_image01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_discount_image01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/discount_image01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                          <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/discount_text_"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Hello"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/discount_text__"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Hello"
                                android:visibility="gone"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#d3d3d3"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer_mans_image01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_mens_image01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/mens_image01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mens_text__"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hello"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mens_textPrice_"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hello"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_mens_name01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mens_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hello"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_mens_price01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mens_textPrice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hello"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Output show below image:-

[image]

when i drag drawer layout show below image:-

[image]

after click on menu list is close.

Am also want listview is also open on click on App name..I am new in android developing help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: i think your scrollview is over ExpandableListView which causing you this problem why this type of layout?

Comment: can u describe or share pic what output you want from this layout

Comment: items in ScrollView do you want all that below expandable list view or anything else?

Comment: no i want normally as any app show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92738/discussion-between-pavan-and-anand-jain).

Answer (score 0):

try with below xml and let me know if it works or not

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">






            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/list_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/line3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                        android:id="@+id/slider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp" />

                    <!--        <View
                                android:id="@+id/grad_offer_details_view"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="5dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>  -->

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/grad_offer_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Grab Before Time Runs Out"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/yellow_draw_line"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#FF00FF00"/>


                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollbars="none">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer_image01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_image01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/line1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:visibility="gone">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/image01"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/text_"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Hello"
                                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/text__"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Hello"
                                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/discount_and_offers_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp"
                        android:background="#d3d3d3"/>
                    <!-- android:background="@android:color/gray" -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/discount_and_offers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Discount And Offers"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/green_draw_line"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#FF00FF00"/>

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollbars="none">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer_discount_image01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_discount_image01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:visibility="gone">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/discount_image01"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/discount_text_"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Hello"
                                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/discount_text__"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Hello"
                                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#d3d3d3"/>

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer_mans_image01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_mens_image01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/mens_image01"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/mens_text__"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/mens_textPrice_"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_mens_name01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/mens_text"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_inner_mens_price01"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/mens_textPrice"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello"
                                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>




    </FrameLayout>
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

        </ExpandableListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No its not working add applying your code list is always open and not close it.

Comment: is ExpandableListView  your drawer menu

Comment: actually i removed it for test at my side now check updated answer with toolbar @AnandJain

Comment: @AnandJain if it helped you then you can accept the answer.

Comment: firstly i tested then if it work then i surely accept

Comment: this work in only emulator but run in actual device this show only black background